# Will a PDF imported and rasterized in GIMP at 500 DPI lose quality when exported back to PDF?

Tags: gimp, pdf, rasterization

Suppose I have a single-page 5x8 PDF with text on it, exported from LaTeX. If I import this PDF into GIMP at 500 DPI, then export it as a PDF, will this process make it show any loss of its original quality when viewed at its original size?

Comment: GIMP is the wrong kind of software for this. Opening a PDF in GIMP will rasterize everything. While you may get away with doing that if the resolution is high enough, it's not optimal. Use a vector image editor instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking.... Raster images can be lower quality than vector images, since vector images are *resolution independent*. But this **depends greatly** on the *content* of any image(s). Type specifically can suffer when rasterized depending upon its' size. Rasterized type can lose much more than simple vector outline data, it can also lose hinting data for the type. Hinting is not typically a major issue above 12pt type, but it's something to be aware of. (Hinting dictates to output devices *how* a type glyph should be drawn not merely its shape - i.e. which stroke to draw first in what direction, then second, etc.)

That being posted, there may be little loss in quality if the PPI of the rasterized image is high enough and suits output desires.

Whether or not something "shows any loss" depends upon the *actual* image(s), desired final usage, or future alterations.

It's not possible to be definitive in stating either "yes" or "no" here. There are too many variables. Sometimes it's fine, others it's not. The best you can do is *try it* and see if the rasterization is a problem for *your* images/project.

One thing you **will** absolutely realize is a 5x8" PDF containing type in vector form is going to be *remarkably smaller* in file size (kb) than a 5x8" PDF containing a single raster image.

Vector type in PDFs is often comprised of an *embedded subset* of the original font. Meaning the `a` glyph is embedded. Each time `a` is used, the pdf refers to the embedded glyph. Embed once and use as often as needed, no extra file weight (kb). That subset embedding takes *far less* kb than a collection of pixels for each and every glyph each and every time that glyph is used.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. I ended up finding a solution by editing the PDF via Inkscape, which seems to retain the PDF's vectorization.

Comment: Hi @Lijishe Yep.. Inkscape or Illustrator are indeed better options for vector-based PDFs `:)`